# Call onClick of checkbox manually in PHP

Tags: php, checkbox, onclick

I want to call onClick method of checkbox manually because I am showing the checkbox as 'checked' based on certain condition.

below is my code

```
if(in_array($rs['item_number'],$it_arr))
    echo "<td><span class='data'>-</span><input type=checkbox onclick=\"AddItemRow(this)\" checked/></td>";
else
    echo "<td><span class='data'>-</span><input type=checkbox onclick=\"AddItemRow(this)\" /></td>";
```

In the code above I want to call AddItemRow(this) method and also want to pass variable this which is accepted by that method..
How can I do this?

Comment: You can't call `onClick` by default. You need to do so on document ready. :-/

Comment: i think you want something like this [http://jsfiddle.net/jgs9K/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/jgs9K/2/)

Comment: @PankitKapadia: Please post it as answer so that I can accept It.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not call `onClick` event using PHP. You will need to do so by using JS, You will need to check if checkbox is `checked` on `document ready`.

Here is an example:

[**JS FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jgs9K/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>AddItemRow('".$var."')</script>";
```

Comment: and what will be the $var value?

Comment: @Pratik - what value you are getting for `this`?

Comment: From looking at your code, I would guess $rs['item_number']. Whatever identifies your item / row. $var was just a placeholder example of how to pass a variable to a JavaScript method from PHP.

Comment: `<input type=checkbox onclick=\"AddItemRow(this)\" checked/>` here this must be the checkbox reference. So how could I send the current checkbox referece through php?

Comment: You could pass an id through PHP to JavaScript to later identify an element using getElementByID in JS. But your current code handles that already with 'this'.

Comment: @Pratik - check the link which i've added in my comment !!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand the question, but I think it has some underlying confusion about the nature of client-server systems.  Your PHP script runs on the server and it creates the HTML, CSS and JavaScript that gets sent to the client machine.  The JavaScript runs on the client machine, but it does not get to run until after the PHP on the server has completed its task and disconnected.  In other words, the onClick() function in JavaScript cannot be triggered by PHP, it can only be triggered by the client (human) or some action in the client (JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

There's an entire practice that says it's a bad idea to have inline functions/styles.
 consider

**JS**

```
var myvar=15;

    document.getElementById('input_id').onclick=function(){AddItemRow(myvar);};
```

**HTML**

```
<input id="input_id" type="checkbox"  />
```

- you missed quotes between `checkbox` in your input
  like thatu can pass your variable `myvar`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here we can use jquery which ill check for checked case and will trigger a click function
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


$(function(){

    if($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').val()){

        var obj = $('input[type=checkbox]');
        AddItemRow(obj);            
    }

});

function AddItemRow(obj){
    console.log(obj);
    obj.attr('checked', true);
}
</script>

if(in_array($rs['item_number'],$it_arr))
    echo "<td><span class='data'>-</span><input type=checkbox onclick=\"AddItemRow(this)\" checked/></td>";
else
    echo "<td><span class='data'>-</span><input type=checkbox onclick=\"AddItemRow(this)\" /></td>";
```